# How do you connect to an AWS RDS postgres db from cloud foundry on PWS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-rds, cloud-foundry

I am using PWS to run my rails app but we are having trouble connecting to our postgres db instance running on AWS RDS.  We tried unbinding any ElephantSQL services we have and changing the DATABASE_URL ENV to the postgres login url, but that did not work.  We also have tried updating our database.yml but nothing happens there either.

This seems like it SHOULD be easier but it appears that the database.yml is not read on PWS.

How can we connect to our RDS db from a PWS instance?

Comment: Is the RDS database accessible from PWS? Can you connect to it manually?

Comment: @jdno yes sir - no problem.  If I do psql postgres://... then I can get in without issue from my osx terminal

Comment: Are you trying with cups to make connection between app and AWS RDS?

Comment: @KumareshBabu what's "cups?"

Comment: @JoshL CUPS is Create User Provided Service. If services is not available in Marketplace, then we have to create user provided service by configuring service endpoint and credentials. I though you created user provided service for AWS RDS to establish connection between an app and AWS RDS.

Comment: Thanks @kamaresh.  My issue is that I'm NOT a sysop and the entire reason I'm trying CF is to NOT have to deal with this nonsense.  So far heroku has CF completely beat in terms of worryfree server hosting.

Comment: The behavior here varies depending on your Rails version (https://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/ruby/gsg-ror.html#database-configuration), with older versions trying to do a little magic.  What version are you using?  Also, how are you setting the DATABASE_URL?  Check `cf env` to make sure it is set the way you want & run `cf restage` to make sure it has taken effect.

Comment: @DanielMikusa sorry for the VERY old reply.  I used CUPS to create a user service with the RDS host, dbname, username and password and bound it to my app.  But how do I know USE IT?  Do I use the VCAP_SERVICES env variable in database.yml or something else?  It's crazy there is not more documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
  port:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_PORT"] %>
  database: <%= ENV["DATABASE_NAME"] %>
  pool: 15
  encoding: utf8
  username: <%= ENV["DATABASE_USER_NAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>

psql --host=xxxxx-prod.xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=multilang_prod_xxxx --password --dbname=multilang_prod_xxxx
```

try manually connecting

```
psql --host=multilang-prod.cnvr5o86qwm2.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=multilang_prod --password --dbname=multilang_prod

   sudo apt install postgresql-client-common
   sudo apt install  postgresql-client-9.5
```